# Configure svn diff and meld not use a tmp file

Tags: svn, meld

svn diff --diff-cmd=meld src/file.c

When I do a diff using meld using the command above it seems to make a copy of src/file.c in a tmp file and then opens up the diff.

I think before svn 1.7 it used to use the local file. Using the local file is convenient when I want to edit the file with meld. Is there a way to get svn 1.7 to use a local file when opening up the diff in meld.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396176
Short answer: it has to do with properties: 'svn:keywords' and 'svn:eol-style'